# I can't display my Avatar and Username in an embed on startup (discord.js) "Cannot read property 'user' of null"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new on javascript and I wanted to send a message in a channel everytime the BOT gets online. I managed to do that but I want that the BOT automatically changes my username and my avatar in the footer whenever I change them. This is my code so far.

```
    console.log('Connected as ' + client.user.tag);
    const MyUsername = client.guilds.resolve(testserver).members.resolve(creator)

    const OnlineEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Online!')
    .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('By ' + MyUsername.user.username);

    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('789877657307185219');
    channel.send(OnlineEmbed);
    channel.send('=======================')
    });
```

'testserver' and 'creator' are in my config.json file and they are my Server ID and my User ID.

When I try to run the code it says
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null

Comment: Where did you define and initialize the `client` variable?

Comment: at the start i think...

const client = new Discord.Client();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Presence Intent in your dev portal for your bot, otherwise the bot is not able to read the user in the 'ready' event.